# a 3 level deep relationship in Ecto -- how to preload

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have quite a several level relationship  of models in my project. In a controller I have this:

```
var1 = Repo.get!(Model1, 123) |> Repo.preload([child_items1:  :child_items2])
```

This works fine but I have to go one level deeper.

Namely each `child_items2` many `child_items3`.  Now, how can I preload `child_items3` for each `child_items2`?

Comment: Try `Repo.get!(Model1, 123) |> Repo.preload([child_items1:  [child_items2: :child_items3])`, let's see what happens.

Comment: Worked for me! This should be an answer rather than a comment

Answer (score 0):

I usually use scopes. For example in my Model(1) I will have a `with_model2` function that preloads the Model2. So to load 3 associations in a row, I'd have something like:

```
def with_model2(query \\ __MODULE__) do
  from query, preload: [model2: ^Model2.with_model3]
end
```

for my Model(1). And then you get the idea, the Model2 would have

```
def with_model3(query \\ __MODULE__) do
  from query, preload: :model3
end
```

I actually never went 3 level deep, but I just assume that would work.

Answer (score 0):

For others:
The [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#preload/3) actually says:
Nested associations can also be preloaded in both formats:

```
Repo.all from p in Post,
       preload: [comments: :likes]
```

or in one query

```
Repo.all from p in Post,
       join: c in assoc(p, :comments),
       join: l in assoc(c, :likes),
       where: l.inserted_at > c.updated_at,
       preload: [comments: {c, likes: l}]
```